# Free geocode API allowing store names and coordinates

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

My application should allow users to store events and their locations and then perform search on them - so I need those locations in my database with their names and latitudes/longitudes. Google API doesnt allow storing anything else but place IDs so I have to find something else that can autocomplete/suggest places on UI and allow storing it my database.
Does anyone know such a good service?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your points in your DB based on each point Lat & Long values. So when user is searching somewhere you have his current location(Lat-Long), Therefore you can search in your DB and get the distance of each saved point with current location and retrieve the results you want to show (i.e in JSON format).

1. In client-side use some auto-complete jquery library to show the nearby places and somethings like that (with additional information).
2. Google Map API has a service that you can show some custom marker on the map with your custom configuration like marker icon, description and etc. You can show your additional information in description as HTML format.
   You can see some example here:
   [Customizing a Google Map: Custom Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/custom-markers)

Hope these tips would be helpfull. Regards.

Comment: I cannot store suggested places names and lat/long because Google API doesnt allow it by the license.

Comment: As I mentioned you can use Google Map API Service to get your customized response like this URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=new%20&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=____&components=country:us&location=37.773564,-122.445230&radius=500
As you see in this URL, you can set your parameters based on your requirements

Comment: this is from here https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies?hl=en 
Applications using the Google Places API Web Service are bound by the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. Section 10.5.d of the terms states that you must not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content except under the limited conditions stated in the terms.

Note that the place ID, used to uniquely identify a place, is exempt from the caching restriction. You can therefore store place ID values indefinitely. The place ID is returned in the place_id field in Google Places API Web Service responses.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly I've found an answer that helps me:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/hNc1OOU6Zm8

So I can use some Google's data under some conditions.